# C programming: How do I use realloc in this program?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have to write a program that stores and prints out integers from memory.  I have to use realloc.  Basically, the program allocates size for 2 ints.  When input is given 2 ints it should reallocate space for 1 more int and prints out double.  Next, when input is given 3 ints, it should allocate 2 more spaces for int and prints out double.. and so on..

```
Test cases:

input file in.0:
------
4
------

expected output:
------
4
------

=================================================

input file in.1:
------
4 5
------

expected output:
------
4
5
double
------

==================================================

input file in.2:
------
4 5 3
------

expected output:
------
4
5
double
3
double
------

===================================================

input file in.3:
------
4 5 3 2 9
------

expected output:
------
4
5
double
3
double
2
9
double
```

I wrote this program but it does not allocate memory properly.  Can someone guide me in the write direction please?

```
int main(void)
{
    int c;

    int digit;
    int count = 0;
    int d_size = 1;
    int init_size = 2;
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * init_size);

    while((c = scanf("%i", &digit)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == 1)
        {
            *(p+count) = digit;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not valid");
        }

        printf("%i\n", digit);

        if (count >= 2)
        {
            printf("double\n");
            p = (int *) realloc(p, sizeof(int) * d_size);
            d_size = d_size * 2;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't damn cast the damn return value of the damn realloc!

Comment: "does not allocate memory properly" - please be more specific.  In what way does it not work?

Comment: @H2CO3: +1 I have a canned comment for this because I see it *soooooo* often around here.  This is not C++, don't cast the return value of `malloc` (or `realloc` in this case)!

Comment: +1 from me for you too. That makes my eyes vomit.

Answer (score 4):

Your `init_size` is 2, but your `d_size` is 1. First of all, make `d_size` equal to `init_size`. Second, you need to do `d_size = d_size * 2` before the `realloc` so you would actually increase the size.

---

Side note: `realloc` will fail if out of memory. If you write:

```
p = realloc(p, ...);
```

in case of failure, you will lose the memory previously allocated. You should always use `realloc` like this:

```
enlarged = realloc(p, ...);
if (enlarged == NULL)
    // handle error
else
    p = enlarged;
```

---

Side note 2: You may end up changing type of your pointer. Better not repeat it. Instead of

```
int *p;
p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
```

write:

```
int *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * count);
```

Comment: one second too late for me, wanted to write exactly the same